# amCharts5 - How to Hide X-Axis Labels on Gannt Chart?

Tags: javascript, amcharts5

I'm trying to adapt this code ([amCharts 5 Gantt Chart](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/gantt-chart/)) to my project and want to hide the x-axis labels on this amCharts 5 gannt chart. Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their demo code, just before the following...

```
chart.appear(1000, 100);
```

Add the following...

```
xAxis.hide();
```

If that doesn't work for you, perhaps do it after the chart is shown (`chart.appear(1000, 100);`)?

More information: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/reference/axislabel/#hide_method